# What is the equivalent of 'hungry' for breathing?

Tags: single-word-requests

*Hungry* for eating. *Thirsty* for drinking. *Tired* for sleeping.

What can we use for the need or desire to breathe?

I can think of saying "hungry for air," "thirsty for a breath," "gasping for a breath." Is there anything specific for *breathe*?

Comment: Suffocating? Asphyxiating?  Dying?

Comment: Breathless, perhaps?

Comment: Why not gasping for breath? It is the most commonly used phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the word you're looking for is [winded](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/winded?s=t).

Comment: You're hungry when you need to eat; you're not constantly eating.  Ditto for thirsty and drinking.  On the other hand, you're always breathing.  The suggestion of winded is the best alternative, however; it describes the condition you're in when exertion has caused you to require more oxygen, and therefore, you have to breathe harder and deeper to keep up.  Another way of saying this is "out of breath."

Comment: @Terroba I like this as the best option, and something could play with. I don't think it often gets used in the sense I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest *hypoxic*, although it sounds a bit technical.

Comment: Nothing wrong with technical, *the human body senses pure* [hypoxia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypoxia_%28medical%29) *poorly* and *is often a pathological condition*.

Answer (score 0):

As the words you use for eating, drinking and sleeping indicate a state, you might want to go with fainting.

Answer (score 0):

**Burning**... for a breath of fresh air.  Fire consumes oxygen to exist without it it dies as do we.

http://science.howstuffworks.com/environmental/earth/geophysics/fire.htm